# GWT - Move panel to new browser tab/window

Tags: gwt

I'm working on a GWT application that has the following layout:
- on top there's Menu Bar
- below that screen is separated into two panel by Split Layout Panel

When user clicks on a label in Menu Bar relevant information is show below in the left part of the screen. Then user clicks on an action item on that left part of the screen, and relevant information on that action item is displayed on the right part of the screen.
Clicking on an action item on the right part of the screen may also change relevant information on left part of the screen.

I want to extend on this by giving a possibility to drag/drop the panel on the right part of the screen to another browser tab/window. After that the right and left part of the screen should remain connected as if they are in the same browser tab/window.
Also, that new tab/window should only display that right panel, while Menu Bar and left panel, along with Split Layout Panel should not be present (this is less important but it would be great if it can be done).
Another important thing is that current visual representation of application is not changed but only extended with this functionality.

Is that something that can be done and if it is how to do it?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to use "HTML5" native drag and drop to drag between browser instances, so that would limit browser support. Both tabs would already have to have your code loaded into them so they could respond to these events.

If you have a server back end (not just static HTML/JS) then you could communicate via the server. Otherwise maybe "HTML5" client side storage to store blobs of data describing the panel contents. Probably easier re-render in the new browser/tab.